# Unbounded closed operator commuting with Riemann integral.

Tags: functional-analysis, riemann-integration

Let A be an Unbounded operator with dense domain $D(A)$ in a Banach space $X$. Can we have a continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$, taking values on $D(A)$ but with $Af$ not Riemann Integrable as a function $[a,b]\to X$?.